# Create "Winform" in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to create a form in MS Access 2007 that is not dependent on a recordset?  I want to create a form that would just handle simple calculations, but would not rely on any data from the database.

This is the code I've tried to use, but when I run it I get a compile error "Method or data member not found."

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click()
Dim TotalCost As Integer
Dim DisposalCost As Integer
Dim CostRatio As Integer
TotalCost = txtTotalCost.Text
DisposalCost = txtDisposalCost.Text
CostRatio = TotalCost / DisposalCost
lblCostRatio.Text = CostRatio
End Sub
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or do I need to just create a winform to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. Do not refer to the `.text` property, the text property is only available when a control has focus. if you must use a property - it is not required - use `.value`.

For labels, you do indeed need the `.caption` property.

There are advantages in using a textbox for the answer, because you can set it to a function or a calculation. For example, you can set the control source to:

```
= txtText1 / txtText2
```

You can prevent the results textbox from being edited with the `locked` and / or `enabled` properties. To ensure that the calculations is performed, you will need to set the `format` property to a number or currency format.

Comment: Thanks. Nice Answer.  Should also note that I did have to use .caption for it to display.

Answer (score 4):

If `lblCostRatio` is a label control, your error message is due to this line:

```
lblCostRatio.Text = CostRatio
```

A label control does not have a `.Text` property.  Look at altering its `.Caption` property instead.